# When to convert UTC datetime to user's local for multi-language support

Tags: php, datetime

I'm aware this subject has been covered numerous times. Fast answer is always "the later the better". But I'm unsure just how soon it'd be considered bad practice.

I'm using datetimes all over my app. If I leave it to the very last moment i.e. right before sending data to the views, I'll have to do boring repetitive code for every single datetime like that:

```
$dateOBJ = new DateTime($date);
$timezoneOBJ = new DateTimeZone($user_timezone);
$dateOBJ->setTimezone($timezoneOBJ)->format($my_format);
```

When I could do just once in the beginning of the script:

```
date_default_timezone_set($user_timezone);
```

And convert all fields right after (or during, if I was to use SQL functions) querying from UTC to user's. Therefore, a single model routine would deal with it for me and I'd never be worried about it again, even for form inputs.

Why is that bad practice?

Comment: As per my own opinion always save the time in database for a fixed time zone, and at time of display to display it according to users time zone. I don't think it have to be considered as a bad practice. As it's more relevant to show users information with respect to there own time zone .

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned UTC. Database datetimes are UTC. I just can't see a real world situation where converting timezones on query time would result in consistency problems in my business logic.

Answer (score 1):

A timestamp or date/time *value* is an absolute point in time, a precise point in human history. It doesn't matter how this timestamp is stored exactly, there are many formats which all resolve to the same *point in time*.
A human-readable time format in a specific timezone in a locale-specific format is just a very specific way of *presenting* that point in time to the user. This is inherently a *presentation layer* thing, not something the model is dealing with.

Maybe as a better example, take the numeric value `123456.789`. This is an absolute numerical value in a pure mathematical sense. This is the value that you base calculations on in your model. However, in the UI, this number may be presented as "123,456.789" or "123.456,789" or "12,34,56.789" or any other specific formatting, depending on what the user expects. You'd only format it this way right in your templates:

```
<p><?php echo number_format($number); ?></p>
```

You should do the same with timestamps for the same reasons. If you think the code to do so is too long, then make it shorter:

```
<p><?php echo format_my_date($date); ?></p>
```

or:

```
<p><?php echo $myCustomDateObject->formatLocal($locale); ?></p>
```

or:

```
$dateTimeFormatter = new MyDateTimeFormatter($userLocale, $userTimezone);

...

<p><?php echo $dateTimeFormatter->format($date); ?></p>
```

Comment: What's a real world situation where converting to user's timezone on query time and using the same timezone in my business logic would result in consistency problems?

Comment: Also, yes, I think the code is too long and repetitive to be put in templates. And using a custom function to do all that would shorten code, but then again, 3 function calls being called by another function call. Think of a big array iteration. Can you enlighten me providing examples of consistency problems if I was to just simply convert timezone on the queries or right after it?

Comment: In terms of MVC, which is just common sense separation of concerns: somewhere in the model you get data from the database, inside the model you do business logic calculations with the data from the database, and in the view you present the data. If you format data while getting it from the database, you're mixing presentation logic into your business logic, and need to *consider* different timestamp representations in your business logic. This is just messy any which way you turn it. It may be fine for trivial code, but not when your application grows.

Answer (score 0):

As per my own opinion always save the time in database for a fixed time zone, and at time of display to display it according to users time zone. I don't think it have to be considered as a bad practice. As it's more relevant to show users information with respect to there own time zone .